# sharepoint workflow 2013 approve task programatically

Tags: c#, sharepoint, sharepoint-2013, sharepoint-workflow, workflow-manager-1.x

I am working on SharePoint workflows 2013 the requirement i came across is to approve the task from c# code. however i am not able to get task associated with listItem.

```
listItem.Workflows;
listItem.Tasks;
```

these both properties are giving me 0 in the count.

can anyone find the solution to approve the task for sharepoint workflows 2013.